# How can I stop Android WebView from changing the capitalization of the Headers?

Tags: android, android-webview

So With and Android WebVIew I am adding some Headers to a redirect like so.

```
webView?.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean {
        if(!url!!.contains("ourwebsite/redirect/"))
            return false

        val extraHeaders: MutableMap<String, String> = mutableMapOf()
        extraHeaders.put("Auth_Header, "some token")
        extraHeaders.put("Id_Header, "some username")

        view?.loadUrl(url, extraHeaders)
        return false

    }
```

But the authentication was failing so I got some logs from our server folks and The headers have had the capitalization removed so they look like this now:

```
    "auth_header, "some token"
    "id_header, "some username"
```

How can I make android WebView, respect the capitalization of my headers?!

Answer (score 0):

From [RFC 2616 - "Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1"](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html), [Section 4.2 - "Message Headers"](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2):

> Each header field consists of a name followed by a colon (":") and the field value. Field names are case-insensitive.

The server needs to ignore the case for header names.